# How to Publish/Update website through FinalBuilder taking code from subversion?

Tags: finalbuilder

What I am doing is 'checkout' (if its new) or 'update' website code from subversion.
Then I compile all code, proceeds if successfully compiled and FTP all compiled to another location where Website is hosted replacing all existing code.
All is done in Final Builder 7.

My question is how I put ONLY CHANGED FILES (last commit on Subversion) on FTP location after successful build and compiled in FB7, and files should be published?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds as if you would need to keep a cache of files from previous build, and then check and compare each of them using "File Compare" action.

But what is the motivation behind it? Just replace the whole build output. Attempting segmental updates will inevitably lead to something not being copied or updated.